# Convert Markdown to pdf with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I'm working in a jupyter notebook, and I'm working on a markdown file.  I'm using a mac with Sierra 10.12.16.  I'd like to convert the markdown to a pdf and I'm wondering what the easiest way to do that would be.  I've read a lot of posts about installing things like pandoc or using packages in atom.  I'm wondering if there isn't a simple way with the jupyter notebook to convert the markdown file to pdf.  It really seems like there should be, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  You can just paste the markdown code in to a cell in a jupyter notebook and change the dropdown menu below "Widgets" in the notebook from "code" to "markdown".  Then hit shift enter and it renders the markdown.  You can then download the notebook as pdf.